# Why the worst case of hast table's time complexity is O(n)

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

I have read wikipedia, since accessing a hast table is just simply by array index like `hast_table[index]`, so it should be `O(1)`, Why the worst case of hast table's time complexity is O(n). And what is the worst case?

Comment: Worst-case: all elements are hashed into the same bucket. The worst-case in general is the consequence of limited memory (or having an infinite amound of memory: non-perfect hashing). But take my comment with a grain of salt as analysis can be much more complex, e.g. [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) + [dearmortization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) strategies.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2d9b_nEzoA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash table of capacity 1, that used side chaining, degenerates into a linked list, causing lookups to require linear searches across the single bucket of the table.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists